# Saltstack: directory clean excluding subdirs

Tags: linux, salt-stack

So I have in nginx/common/init.sls this:

```
nginx:
  pkg:
    - latest

/etc/nginx:
  file.directory:
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 755
    - clean: True
    - require:
      - pkg: nginx

/etc/nginx/conf.d:
  file.recurse:
    - source: salt://nginx/common/files/conf.d
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - clean: True
    - template: jinja
    - recurse:
      - user
      - group
      - mode
    - require_in:
      - file: /etc/nginx

/etc/nginx/vhosts.d:
  file.directory:
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 755
    - makedirs: True
    - require_in:
      - file: /etc/nginx
```

to keep **/etc/nginx** clean from default config files and to seed my own configs into this dir and subdirs. That works fine when I run **highstate**, but when I run **highstate** with **test=true**, it returns a notice:

```
  ID: /etc/nginx
  Function: file.directory
    Result: None
   Comment: The following files will be changed:
      /etc/nginx/conf.d: removed - Removed due to clean
      /etc/nginx/vhosts.d: removed - Removed due to clean
```

which is bad, because prevents me from monitoring of 'clean' highstate, and actually untrue.

I tried to add subdirs in 'requier' of **/etc/nginx**, but result was the same. I also noticed that problem affects only **file.directory** and **file.recurse**, not the **file.managed**. How do I prevent this wrong output of **highstate test=true**?

Comment: From what I've read in the documentation it seems as if this is the output it is supposed to give you,it's not a bad output it's just the way the flag test=True works

Comment: I added `exclude_pat: 'E@(conf.d|vhosts.d|htpasswd)'` to **/etc/nginx** state, it works, but seems to be an ugly workaround.

Comment: what do you suppose might overwrite you nginx config file?

Comment: which one? actually no files are overwritten, there is only notice in test run output